# i am trying to read a file and store the contents of file into three different array

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file and store the contents of file into three different array using below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
# define max 10

int main()
{
        char filename[10];
        int at[max],n=0,i;
        float bt[max];
        char pno[max][2];
        printf("Enter the file name :- ");
        scanf("%s",filename);
        FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"r");
        while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f" ,pno[n],&at[n],&bt[n])!=EOF)
                n++;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%s\t%d\t%f\n",pno[i],at[i],bt[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

my input file is:

```
p1 0 20.0  
p2 2 15.0 
p3 6 27.0 
p4 4 36.0
```

and my output is:

```
p1p2p3p4    0   20.000000
p2p3p4  2   15.000000
p3p4    6   27.000000
p4  4   36.000000
```

I don't know why in first line of output along with p1, p2p3p4 is coming and same for 2 and 3 line.

Comment: Suggest `while(fscanf(fp, "%2s %d %f" , pno[n], &at[n], &bt[n]) != 3)` instead od `while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f" ,pno[n],&at[n],&bt[n])!=EOF)` after changing `char pno[max][2];` to `char pno[max][3];`. Also, `scanf("%s",filename);` --> `scanf("%9s", filename);` and check the result of `fopen` to see if it was successful. And add a check for `n` which breaks the loop when `n == max` after `n++;` so that there won't be an overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that strings in C have a special terminator character, so a string of two characters actually needs to be three characters long.

If you do not have the space for the terminator character, then your `fscanf` call will write that special terminator out of bounds of your array, leading to *undefined behavior*.

The fix is very simple, change the declaration of `pno` to this:

```
char pno[max][3];
```

---

You might also want to change that `fscanf` call, to make sure that it will not attempt to store more than two (not including the terminator) characters in the array:

```
fscanf(fp, "%2s %d %f" ,pno[n],&at[n],&bt[n])
```

This will help in case the input file is corrupted in some way.

You might also want to change the condition to e.g.

```
while (fscanf(...) != 3)
```

as that will also detect problems with the input file.

Comment: thank you very much your suggestion helped me to rectify code and now its working fine.But sir i have a confusing , how fscanf work to read multiple line .

Comment: @SaurabhKashyap The functions in the [`scanf` family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) doesn't really read lines, it more or less reads white-space delimited values, with a newline being one of that white-space. If you want to be sure that you read one line at a time then you should use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then you can use `sscanf` on the line you read.